# Are there any examples of weighted edit distance genome alignments?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-analysis, literature, sequence-alignment

It has been said that weighted edit distance is a preferred way to compare/align genomes in practice, e.g., when identifying genetically similar patients. I wonder if there are some concrete examples when weighted edit distance is used this way and I am particularly interested to see some example weight tables. Some links to research papers showing such examples would be very useful.

Comment: Hi and welcome to bio.SE! I made some edits to your question including the title. Feel free to roll back, but I think this should help it get to the right people!

Comment: Where did you read  that "weighted edit distance is a preferred way to compare/align genomes in practice"?